# Synonyms of "Pied Piper"

Tags: synonyms

The phrase *pied piper* is used to refer to "a person who induces others to follow or imitate him or her, especially by means of false or extravagant promises." Does it have synonyms?

Comment: Variegated flautist.

Comment: It reminds me of Ivan Susanin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Susanin)

Comment: Are you looking for a yes/no answer (without presenting synonyms), or are you looking for the synonyms themselves? If the latter, please [edit] your question to explain what quality the term *pied piper* lacks and which you're trying to find in a synonym.

Comment: It has synonyms, metaphors, allusions and comparisons to present days.  What has your research revealed?

Comment: AKA a false prophet, or even a used-car salesman.

Comment: That's not the only meaning of *Pied Piper*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pied%20piper) has "one that offers strong but delusive enticement, "a leader who makes irresponsible promises," and simply "a charismatic person who attracts followers." You need to define a *specific* meaning that you're looking for.

Comment: It could also be a "magician" and his "smoke and mirrors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a different connotation, but "siren" could be a synonym here, in that it also uses an analogy to a mythological creature to refer to someone who lures people under false pretences. Of course, "siren" has a sexual connotation that "pied piper" lacks; both refer to a seduction of sorts, but "siren" is much more closely related to ideas of beauty and lust.

Answer (score -1):

> ## [Trickster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trickster)
>
> : one who tricks: such as 
>   a : a dishonest person who defrauds others by trickery 
>   b : a person (such as a stage magician) skilled in the use of tricks and illusion 
>   c : a cunning or deceptive character appearing in various forms in the folklore of many cultures